# JS not working on data loaded from ajax only

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I load an image gallery built from PHP and I apply this JS code to have a CSS "overlay" when I click on the image.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".button").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "action.php",
            method: "get",
            data: {
                id: $(this).attr("data-action")
            },
            success: openOverlay
        });
    });
    function openOverlay(html_content) {
        // Clear out the overlay-content
        $("#overlay-content").html("");
        // Add new stuff in
        $("#overlay-content").html(html_content);
        $("#overlay").css("display", 'block').css("opacity", '1');
        $("#mask").css("display", 'block').css("opacity", '1');
    }
    function hide() {
        mask.style.display = "none";
        mask.style.opacity = "0";
        overlay.style.display = "none";
        overlay.style.opacity = "0";
    }
</script>
```

Everything works well.  Now I've added a second AJAX to load more image when I get to the bottom of the page.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight == $(document).height()) {
        $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').show();
        $.ajax({
            url: "loadmore.php",
            method: "get",
            data: {
                id: "5"
            },
            success: function(html) {
                if (html) {
                    $("#postswrapper").append(html);
                    $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();
                } else {
                    $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').html('<center>No more posts to show.</center>');
                }
            }
        }); // close AJAX
    }
});
```

And that works well also, when I get to the bottom of the page, it loads more images. No issues there.

**My problem**:  The button click only works on the first loaded data that is loaded with the HTML, it doesn't work on the images being loaded by the AJAX.

Here is my html:

```
<div style="background:url(../blogimages/<? echo $blog2['img_url']; ?>); 
                    background-size:cover;
                    background-position: center; 
                    overflow:hidden;" id="box-item" class="button" data-action="<? echo $blog2['blogimage_id']; ?>">
    <div id="mouseover">
        <span id="plus">READ MORE</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the echo from the AJAX `loadmore.php`:

```
while($blog2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{  
   $html .='
    <div style="background:url(../blogimages/'.$blog2['img_url'].'); 
                background-size:cover;
                background-position: center; 
                overflow:hidden;" 
                    id="box-item" class="button" data-action="'.$blog2['blogimage_id'].'">
              <div id="mouseover">
                <span id="plus">READ MORE</span>
              </div>
    </div>';

     }  // close while tag

    echo $html;
    exit;
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong for the button click not to execute on the data loaded from AJAX? It works perfectly in the first image loaded with the HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
$(document).on('click', '.button', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
            url: "action.php",
            method: "get",
            data: {
                    id: $(this).attr("data-action")
            },
            success: openOverlay

    });
});
```

You could replace `document` with the container that being modified by AJAX callback, I see it better to narrow down the clicking events area. It should be `#postswrapper` in this case.

This binding method matches `event.target` against the passed selector (`.button`), if true then it does whatever this binding function has.

Comment: Could you help explain why, for other's who may come across this question?

Comment: The answer works, but what do you mean by replace document by #postwrapper, like this:  '$(#postswrapper).on('click', '.button', function(e) { ' 
that doesn't work.

Comment: I had forgotten the " " around #postwrpapper...  It works well with that. Thank you for the answer

Comment: It's meant for narrowing down the listening area to avoid conflict with other elements in your DOM tree with `.button` class having different actions.

Answer (score 0):

The button did not exist when the DOM loaded, so you never attached a listener to it. You need to assign a listener to it after it is instantiated.
In your `function openOverlay` add a listener for the new button as it is generated.

```
$( "#yourbutton" ).on( "click", function() {
  //do something on click
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first function is adding a click function to all button class objects. Your second ajax call is then adding to the DOM which weren't originally there to get the click function added.

You just need to add the click function to the new DOM objects created from the ajax in its success function

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that it'll work fine and your problem will be solved.

```
$("body").delegate('.button','click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "action.php",
        method: "get",
        data: {
            id: $(this).attr("data-action")
        },
        success: openOverlay

    });
});
```

click function doesn't work on ajax loaded content

Comment: `.delegate()` has been deprecated since v1.7 and been removed in v1.8 :/